# White line appears across top of page

Tags: background-color, styling, elm

I want a solid background color across all of the page. I get a white line across the top of the page. What do I need to do to get the whole page one color?

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing(..)


mainStyle =style[ ( "background-color", "#ff44aa" )]

main=body[mainStyle][div[] [h5[][text"waah"]]]
```

Comment: might be padding/margin on the body

Comment: Did you find the solution?  I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Your code results in HTML with two bodies. You could instead use CSS to specify the style of the body and then just use:

```
main = 
    div[] [h5[][text"waah"]]
```

Comment: @NielRyan You need to have a minimal setup for elm which requires a mount point for your application. Typically this is a div within the body tag of an HTML document. Because of this the body does exist already and should not be created via elm code again.

Comment: @chromate that has helped find a solution

Answer (score 0):

This works in providing a solid background color:

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing(..)


mainStyle =style[ ( "background-color", "#ff44aa" )
                  ,( "height", "100vh")
                  ,( "margin", "0px")
                  ]

main=
    div[] [h5[mainStyle][text"waahaa"]]
```